# Send sequence of Embedded-messages in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a welcome bot that is going to send the first message, when the person hits a button/emoji below, the next message will come. Going to post the first message, then the next message underneath. Right now I'm using a so to start it you need to write test.

Any suggestion on how I can make it so?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'test':
        how_channel = client.get_channel(CHANNELNAME)

        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="**Now then, how does everything work? Here's a quick tour!**", 
            description="You can see your progression as a percentage as you progress, click the button below to continue trough!", 
            color=0x00ff00)

        myEmbed.add_field(name="It should only take a few minutes!", value="Press the button below to continue")
        myEmbed.set_footer(text="Christer - How does it work", icon_url="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2619/PNG/512/among_us_discord_icon_156922.png")


        await how_channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

So that was the first message that is getting sent, so I want the underneath message to be sent after a button or emoji has been pressed.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'test':
        how_channel = client.get_channel(CHANNELNAME)

        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="News Feed", 
            description="The #announcements will be your most important channel here! You'll be able to keep up to date with everything which is happening within the server so you'll never miss a beat!", 
            color=0x00ff00)

        myEmbed.add_field(name="It should only take a few minutes!", value="Press the button below to continue")
        myEmbed.set_footer(text="Christer - How does it work", icon_url="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2619/PNG/512/among_us_discord_icon_156922.png")        

        await how_channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

Comment: Use the `wait_for('reaction')` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the buttons, you need to specify the lib you use to implement them so we can help you. For reactions, you need to add one via add_reaction (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.add_reaction) and then redirect the on_reaction_add event to your control with wait_for (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for), as you probably do for messages. Don't forget to set a check in your wait_for.

Example :

```
message = await ctx.send(first_embed)
await message.add_reaction("")
await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check = lambda reaction, user: user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == "")
await ctx.send(second_embed)
```